# Delta table versioning while writing from a Spark structured streaming job

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, spark-structured-streaming, delta-lake

Will writing to a Delta table from a Spark structured streaming job create a version for every micro batch of data written?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

> As you write into a Delta table or directory, every operation is
> automatically versioned.

So, yes you are correct.

Getting the data:

- Using a timestamp
- Using version number

Reference: https://databricks.com/blog/2019/02/04/introducing-delta-time-travel-for-large-scale-data-lakes.html